# Prove that $u=v$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I got the following integral identity
$$\int_{\Omega}\left[H(\nabla u)(\nabla H)(\nabla u)-H(\nabla v)(\nabla H)(\nabla v)\right]\cdot\nabla\left(u-v\right)\;dx=0$$
and i want to prove that $u=v$.

Note that $H$ is a Finsler norm, who is homogeneous of degree 1 and convex. How can I use that? Also, since every two norms are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^N$ there exists a,b>0 so that $a|x|\leq H(x)\leq b|x|$.

Comment: You need some kind of boundary condition, otherwise you can't rule out examples of the form $u-v=\mathrm{const.}$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

What is the derivative of the (nonlinear) functional
$$
u \mapsto \frac 12 \, \int_\Omega H(\nabla u)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
?

Comment: $\int_{\Omega}H(\nabla u)(\nabla H)(\nabla u)$\;dx

Comment: Yes. And you can use this to rewrite your equality.

Comment: Can I use the convexity here? how?

Comment: Yes, convexity is your friend. You essentially need the monotonicity of the derivative of a convex function.

Comment: Also, I put this as a form on inner product something like $$\big\langle J'\left(u\right)-J'(v),u-v\big\rangle=0.$$ But I don't know to prove something like strongly convexity of the functional J. Any hints?

Comment: This depends on your norm $H$. Is it a Hilbert space norm?

Comment: Yes, is a subspace of $H^1_0.$